# Rails Legacy Upgrade NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, rails-upgrade

I recently upgraded an old ruby app from rails 5 to rails 7. Ever since, I have been getting this error. It happens after I run rails s and access the application through the browser (seems like the application builds successfully, I only get the error after loading the web App). The constant referred to is defined as such in `app\models\faculty_w\v1\appointment.rb` :

```
class FacultyW::V1::Appointment
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include AppointmentCommon
  include Swagger::Blocks
  include SwaggerSchemas
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

```
NameError (uninitialized constant FacultyW::V1::Appointment::SwaggerSchemas):

app/models/faculty_w/v1/appointment.rb:5:in `<class:Appointment>'
app/models/faculty_w/v1/appointment.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

app/controllers/apidocs_controller.rb:47:in `<class:ApidocsController>'
app/controllers/apidocs_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

I also tried running zeitwerk:check but I get the same error and no recommendations on how to fix it.

I figured it had something to do with the new autoloader but whenever I add the path to the autoloader in application.rb using `config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/faculty_w/v1)` and `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/faculty_w/v1)` I still get the second half of this error.

I also added `config.autoloader = :classic` to application.rb but that did not change anything

Comment: It must be some kind of an issue with the new loader. But there are not enough details here for a more precise guess.

Comment: What details would you suggest I add

Comment: where is `FacultyW::V1::Appointment::SwaggerSchemas` defined?

Comment: I just edited the question to include that (looks clearer there)

Comment: Rails/Ruby is unable to determine where the `SwaggerSchemas` module is defined. Based on a quick search, it doesn't look like this would be defined by a gem. It would be defined in your codebase.

Comment: I would recommend nesting your class e.g. `module FacultyW; module V1; class Appointment; end;end;end`. This will allow `Module.nesting` to work "correctly" or You could try referring to it as a Top Level constant `::SwaggerSchemas` if that is truly where it lives.

Comment: That worked thank you!!! I changed the module definition to ::SwaggerSchemas